# Pandas dataframe having an additional "layer"

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan,columns=['A','B','C'],index=[0,1,2])
```

Suppose I want an additional "layer" on top of this pandas dataframe, such that column A, row 0 would have its value, column B, row 0 would have a different value, column C row 0 would have something, column A row 1 and so on. So like a dataframe on top of this existing one.

Is it possible to add other layers? How does one access these layers? Is this efficient, i.e. should I just use a separate data frame all together? And one would save these multiple layers as a csv, by accessing the individual layers?, or is there a function that would break them down into different worksheets in the same workbook?

Comment: Worksheets in a workbook? You mean some sort of excel file, not just a `csv`.

Comment: you are right that would not work.. as csv does not have worksheets. So by definition not possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame` [cannot have 3 dimensions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/dsintro.html#dataframe):

> **`DataFrame`** is a **2-dimensional** labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types.

However, there is a way to fake 3-dimensions with [MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/advanced.html):

> **Hierarchical indexing (MultiIndex)**
>
> Hierarchical / Multi-level indexing is very exciting as it opens the door to some quite sophisticated data
>   analysis and manipulation, especially for working with higher
>   dimensional data. In essence, **it enables you to store and manipulate
>   data with an arbitrary number of dimensions in lower dimensional data
>   structures like Series (1d) and DataFrame (2d).**

If you really need that extra dimension go with [`pandas.Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/dsintro.html#panel):

> **`Panel`** is a somewhat less-used, but still important container for **3-dimensional** data.

but don't miss this important disclaimer from the docs:

> **Note:** Unfortunately `Panel`, being less commonly used than `Series` and
>   `DataFrame`, has been slightly neglected feature-wise. A number of
>   methods and options available in `DataFrame` are not available in `Panel`.

There is also [`pandas.Panel4D` (experimental)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/dsintro.html#panel4d-experimental) in the unlikely chance that you need it.

Comment: what about adding a 4th dimension to a panel? is that possible? thanks

Comment: No, there is no 4-dimensional data structure in `pandas`. All you get is 3. But I suspect you only need three. Adding several "layers" doesn't add a dimension, just another layer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ah! Never know about `pandel4d`!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I'm still not sure OP actually *wants* 4 dimensions. Perhaps they can clarify.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga:  Probably not, but a perusal of the docs should make the choice clearer.

Comment: In my particular case I want n-days ahead return for the additional 3rd layer and then I want something like (n+1)-days ahead return for the additional 4th layer

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal sounds to me you could just stick with the `Panel`. Each layer isn't an additional dimension.

Comment: Ok,I will check it out.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal:  It sounds like `days` is your 3rd dimension.  It can of course be represented as 2d. (Perhaps keeping it 2d is best, but whatever works for you.)  Your best bet is to code what you can and when you hit an actual stumbling block post a question with code.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal:  See also the additional link about advanced indexing that I added to my answer.

Comment: As a side note, it looks like there are plans to [deprecate `Panel`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13563) with [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) being the recommendation for higher dimensional data.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: What's the gist of your VBA question?

Comment: I found a workaround in Python. But the gist was that you have multiple rows, you have a date for these rows, which sometimes is duplicated. I then have multiple columns: A,B,C. And there plenty of these columns. In most cases the values for individual columns within duplicated rows will be the same, and I wanted to pinpoint which column(s) is responsible for differences. It may be done with if, and statements, but that would be quite inefficient